# Check if specific field exist in document C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have some invoices data saved in DB and I want to check if the file with specific name exist or not.

I'm using the following code

```
var filename = "extra.png";
MongoClient mongoclient = new MongoClient(db_server_ip);
MongoDatabaseBase myDB = (MongoDatabaseBase)mongoclient.GetDatabase(db_name);
IMongoCollection<Invoice> coll = myDB.GetCollection<Invoice>(collection_name);
var query = Query<Invoice>.EQ(u => u.Metadata.FileName, filename).ToBsonDocument();
var exist= coll.Find(query);
```

It is returning something like that `{find({ "Metadata.FileName" : "extra.png" })}.`

[image]

I've also tried this

```
var filter = Builders<IConvertibleToBsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("FileName", filename);
 var result = coll.Find<IConvertibleToBsonDocument>(filter).ToList();
```

But it is not returning anything, list count is 0, even there are so many documents with that filename in DB.

This is my MongoDb document

[image]

Can't figure out how to check if a document with specific FileName exist or not.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused between `find` and `exists`

`find` finds a document which satisfies a condition - `name:a.png` ll find documents where `name` field contains `a.png` whereas `$exists` checks whether `name` field is present in any of the documents and return.

If you are looking for later case, you can use `Query.Exist` from `C#` driver. Else check whether find returns any document.

Comment: I've also tried this var filter = Builders<IConvertibleToBsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("FileName", filename);
            var result = coll.Find<IConvertibleToBsonDocument>(filter).ToList();  But it is not returning anything, list count is 0, even there are so many document with that filename in DB.

Comment: Show us a document in mongo

Comment: You need to use Metadata.FileName. I think you are showing the doc from the code.

Comment: When I use this var filter = Builders<IConvertibleToBsonDocument>.Filter.Eq(metaData.FileName, filename);  it gives me error System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: field'.